# my Navbar.css is not changing my Navbar.jsx

Tags: css, reactjs

My Navbar is not changing colour.  Do I have the correct path to the Navbar.css file in the Navbar.jsx file?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';

class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-toggleable-md">
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"     type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-   controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                 </button>
                 <div className="container">
                 <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Aquastars New    Website</Link>
                  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse"    id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </nav>
    );
  }
 }

 export default Navbar;
```

Below is the structure of the app[image: Structure of React App]

below is the code for the .css file

```
.navbar-brand {
color: rgb(197, 21, 21);
}

a {
color: #aaa;
font-weight: 200;
}
```

below is what is in my header.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>React App</title>
 </head>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your NavBar.css?

Comment: Are you using any other css packages? Something like bootstrap? Could be overwriting the color you define in `Navbar.css`

Comment: I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn how to use Chrome devtools to debug the problem for yourself. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning React but you may want to try `import * as styles from './styles.css'`, and to use that specific class, `className={styles.yourClass}`

Comment: Sorry Kendra  I don't understand.  I am not sure why Bootstrap keeps overriding my css.

Comment: in the header, is your stylesheet link place after your bootstrap? For more info, check out >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133742/css-bootstrap-overrides-my-own-css or you may want to put `!important` to your style if it still doesn't work but it's not recommended.

Comment: Have you tried adding !important to your css so that it doesn't get overridden?   color: rgb(197, 21, 21) !important;  (I think it's common for Bootstrap3 to override custom CSS, haven't had much experience with Bootstrap4)

Comment: where would I add important Azeame ?

Comment: `.navbar-brand {
color: rgb(197, 21, 21) !important;
}`

Comment: if you have tried to import the specific styling class, add !important, and the order of bootstrap and your styling file is correct so bootstrap wouldn't override your css, then you should ask your teacher or colleague for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by restarting the server.  For some reason, the changes were not carried over from the CSS file.  So I controlled C to stop the server and the restarted it again.

```
npm start
```